# address.send() returns 'true' but transaction doesn't happen

Tags: solidity, transactions, contract-debugging, internal-transactions

I am trying to send ether from a contract to another address. I used the `send` method do that. The function returned `true` but the transaction didn't happen at all. The contract definitely has a lot of balance in it.

Here is my contract code.

```
contract Betting {

  address public ac2 = 0xCB87BDB88EEF4ABC66AE6F1A131D41021C145863;
  address public myaccount = this;
  bool public transferStatus = false;

  event Transfer(address _from, uint256 _value);
  event TransferTo(address _to, uint256 _value);

  function Betting() {

  }

  function sendEther() payable returns (uint) {
    return msg.value;
  }

  function () payable {
   Transfer(msg.sender, msg.value);
  }

  function reward() payable returns (bool) {
    transferStatus = ac2.send(0.05 ether);
    TransferTo(ac2, 0.05 ether);
    return transferStatus;
  }
```

Edit: I found that transactions that are called from within a contract will be stored as internal transactions. Interestingly, My contract doesn't even have an internal transaction tab in [Etherscan](http://etherscan.io)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes etherscan takes a while to display the internal transactions. But everything came in eventually. There was no error in the code.